Dynamic import Nuxt 3 (Nitro)
How can I use dynamic import in nuxt 3 (nitro)?
src/server/api/urls.ts:

This method works
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    const module = await import('../../../utils/transliterate')

    return []
})

But if I move the string into a separate variable, I get the following error:
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    const path = '../../../utils/transliterate'

    const module = await import(path)

    return []
})


Unknown file extension ".ts" for /mnt/projects/projects/.../src/utils/transliterate.ts

I tried to set absolute paths, with and without extensions
